# ob_start and call_user_func not working together

Tags: php

I've created a simple cache system for my website but I got a weird issue. When I call `call_user_func` right after `ob_start`, it's not correctly caught and it stops the execution.

Here is my Caching class code:

```
<?php

class Cache
{
    public static function caching($name, $callback, $duration = 120, $debug = true)
    {
        if ($debug) $start_time = microtime(true);

        // Compute file name
        $cache = 'cache' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name .'_' . md5(join('-', $_POST)) . '.cache';
        $expire = time() - $duration;

        if(file_exists($cache))
        {
            if (filemtime($cache) > $expire)
            {
                // Display content saved into the cache file
                readfile($cache);
                if ($debug) echo '<br />' . (microtime(true) - $start_time * 1000) . 'microseconds';
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // File is too old so we can delete it
                unlink($cache);
            }
        }

        // Init buffer
        ob_start();

        // Do job
        if (function_exists($callback)) call_user_func($callback);
        else echo 'Function ' .$callback. ' doesn\'t exist.';

        // Retrieve buffer
        $page = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // Save buffer to a cache file
        file_put_contents($cache, $page);

        // Display content
        echo $page;

        if ($debug) echo '<br />' . (microtime(true) - $start_time * 1000) . 'microseconds';
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my sample:

```
<?php

require('cache.class.php');

function run()
{
    if (isset($_GET['sid']))
    {
        $sid = htmlentities($_GET['sid']);
        echo 'sid is ' . $sid;
    }
}

Cache::caching('Sample', 'run');
die();
```

So it displays `sid id XXXXX` when it gets called but it doesn't go further in the `caching` method. The line `$page = ob_get_contents();` is never reached and I don't have any error message.

Did I make something wrong or is this a real issue, using both `ob_start` and `call_user_fun` ?

Comment: are you sure that your entire `Caching` function doesn't stop at the `return;` line?

Comment: Yes, i'm totally certain. I've put an `echo` at that line and it's never called.

Comment: Did you turn on error_reporting/display_errors? You should never be developing/testing/debugging with them off in the first place.

Comment: I've already tried to put a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the begining of my files, but it doesn't display any error with the above code. If I forgive a `;` for example, it displays me an error, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Apparently, this was a known issue in `PHP 5.2`. I've asked my hosting service to update it to `5.4` and the problem has been solved.